# Creating "starburst" table from two point features with 1:N relationship using Spatialite?

Tags: spatialite

I have a point feature called site_investigation and another point feature called sample_location which are in a Spatialite database.  They have a 1:N relationship and the primary key is report_id.

```
CREATE TABLE site_investigation (
        fid         INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
        report_id   TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
        geometry    POINT
);
CREATE TABLE sample_location (
        fid            INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
        report_id      TEXT NOT NULL,
        official_name  TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
        geometry    POINT
        FOREIGN KEY(report_id) REFERENCES site_investigation(shz_report_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

I would like to create a table of lines that connects site_investigation to sample_location to form a "starburst" display. I'm a Spatialite novice.

Comment: Are you just looking for something to draw a picture of the database relationship (like old versions of Access did)? Or are you trying to build a foreign key relationship? Or are you trying to show a "starburst" on the map? Can you explain how QGIS fits into this?

Comment: I'm looking to create a "starburst" on the map.   I'm using QGIS to view my data.  I would also be interested in having another Spatialite table that contains these lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll show how to do this in just spatialite.

Lets start with creating the same schema as you showed in the question:

```
-- The schema provided in the question
CREATE TABLE site_investigation (
        fid         INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
        report_id   TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL
);
SELECT AddGeometryColumn('site_investigation', 'geometry', -1, 'POINT', 'XY');

CREATE TABLE sample_location (
        fid            INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
        report_id      TEXT NOT NULL,
        official_name  TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL
);
SELECT AddGeometryColumn('sample_location', 'geometry', -1, 'POINT', 'XY');
```

Note that I've removed the foreign key (since it had a typo, and [sqlite ignores them by default anyway](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_enable)).

We'll need some sample data. The data obviously isn't what you are using, but it should be illustrative. I also didn't have the SRID, so I went with -1 (unknown).

```
-- Fill in some sample data
INSERT INTO site_investigation (report_id, geometry) VALUES ("siteA", MakePoint(5, 10));
INSERT INTO site_investigation (report_id, geometry) VALUES ("siteB", MakePoint(10, 20));

INSERT INTO sample_location(report_id, official_name, geometry) VALUES ("siteA", "sample1", MakePoint (5, 8));
INSERT INTO sample_location(report_id, official_name, geometry) VALUES ("siteA", "sample2", MakePoint (5, 12));
INSERT INTO sample_location(report_id, official_name, geometry) VALUES ("siteA", "sample3", MakePoint (6, 7));
INSERT INTO sample_location(report_id, official_name, geometry) VALUES ("siteA", "sample4", MakePoint (6, 3));

INSERT INTO sample_location(report_id, official_name, geometry) VALUES ("siteB", "sample6", MakePoint (10, 16));
INSERT INTO sample_location(report_id, official_name, geometry) VALUES ("siteB", "sample7", MakePoint (10, 25));
INSERT INTO sample_location(report_id, official_name, geometry) VALUES ("siteB", "sample8", MakePoint (12, 21));
```

To make it prettier, I'll turn on some [formatting options](https://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html):

```
.headers on
.mode column 
.width 10 25 25
```

Note that none of that affects the SQL, just how output is shown. Ignore if if you like.

When writing SQL commands, I recommend simple first, and slow build up:

```
-- Test basic operation
SELECT sample_location.official_name AS Name, AsEwkt(site_investigation.geometry) AS SitePosition, AsEwkt(sample_location.geometry) AS SamplePosition FROM site_investigation, sample_location WHERE site_investigation.report_id = sample_location.report_id;
```

That produces the following:

```
Name        SitePosition               SamplePosition           
----------  -------------------------  -------------------------
sample1     SRID=-1;POINT(5 10)        SRID=-1;POINT(5 8)       
sample2     SRID=-1;POINT(5 10)        SRID=-1;POINT(5 12)      
sample3     SRID=-1;POINT(5 10)        SRID=-1;POINT(6 7)       
sample4     SRID=-1;POINT(5 10)        SRID=-1;POINT(6 3)       
sample6     SRID=-1;POINT(10 20)       SRID=-1;POINT(10 16)     
sample7     SRID=-1;POINT(10 20)       SRID=-1;POINT(10 25)     
sample8     SRID=-1;POINT(10 20)       SRID=-1;POINT(12 21)
```

Now we can change the two points into a line:

```
-- Change column width for layout
.width 10 40
-- Make line
SELECT sample_location.official_name AS Name, AsEwkt(MakeLine(site_investigation.geometry, sample_location.geometry)) AS link_line FROM site_investigation, sample_location WHERE site_investigation.report_id = sample_location.report_id;
```

That produces:

```
Name        link_line                               
----------  ----------------------------------------
sample1     SRID=-1;LINESTRING(5 10,5 8)            
sample2     SRID=-1;LINESTRING(5 10,5 12)           
sample3     SRID=-1;LINESTRING(5 10,6 7)            
sample4     SRID=-1;LINESTRING(5 10,6 3)            
sample6     SRID=-1;LINESTRING(10 20,10 16)         
sample7     SRID=-1;LINESTRING(10 20,10 25)         
sample8     SRID=-1;LINESTRING(10 20,12 21)
```

Which is pretty much what we want. You could just use that as a VIEW, but you asked for a table, so lets go with that:

```
-- Create new table
CREATE TABLE site_links (
        fid            INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
        official_name  TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL
);
SELECT AddGeometryColumn('site_links', 'linkgeom', -1, 'LINESTRING', 'XY');
```

To populate the table, we use the same SELECT (less the AsEwkt() formatting function), just putting an INSERT INTO around it:

```
INSERT INTO site_links (official_name, linkgeom) SELECT sample_location.official_name, MakeLine(site_investigation.geometry, sample_location.geometry) FROM site_investigation, sample_location WHERE site_investigation.report_id = sample_location.report_id;
```

Now we check the results:

```
SELECT official_name, AsEwkt(linkgeom) FROM site_links;
```

Which produces:

```
official_n  AsEwkt(linkgeom)                        
----------  ----------------------------------------
sample1     SRID=-1;LINESTRING(5 10,5 8)            
sample2     SRID=-1;LINESTRING(5 10,5 12)           
sample3     SRID=-1;LINESTRING(5 10,6 7)            
sample4     SRID=-1;LINESTRING(5 10,6 3)            
sample6     SRID=-1;LINESTRING(10 20,10 16)         
sample7     SRID=-1;LINESTRING(10 20,10 25)         
sample8     SRID=-1;LINESTRING(10 20,12 21)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  That was exactly what I was looking for.   I should have asked for a view, but I'll see if I can do it myself.

Comment: A view would be just the same, however instead of ```CREATE TABLE``` and ```INSERT INTO```, it is going to be ```CREATE VIEW site_links AS SELECT sample_location.official_name AS official_name, MakeLine(...)...```

Comment: I just tried to make a view, but it does not show up in qgis.  After looking on SE, I see I had to do something like: INSERT INTO views_geometry_columns (view_name, view_geometry, view_rowid,f_table_name, f_geometry_column,read_only) values  'site_links','geom','rowid','site_investigation','geometry',1).  Now qgis thinks this view is a point feature.