# Create lines between two points, given an ID

Tags: qgis, spatialite, points-to-line

I have a spatialite point table (`p1`) with an additonal column (`pid`) that relates each point to a point in another point table (`p0`) in the same database. I want to create a line between every pair of points where `p1.pid` matches `p0.id`. This is a 1:1 relation.

How can I do that in spatialite or in QGIS 2.14?

Answer (score 2):

A solution was actually buried in [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/92870/70696), which I could modify for my problem:

```
SELECT MakeLine(p0.geom, p1.geometry) AS link_line FROM "buildings_p0" p0, "roadpoints_p1" p1 WHERE p1.pid = p0.id;
```